# .load() only the children of the source html's root?

Tags: jquery

At my `url` I have a piece of html that is wrapped inside a `<tr>`

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="row_edit" href="/sales_item/edit/{{ item.id }}" title="{% trans 'Edit' %}"><i class="icon-pencil"> </i></a>
        <a href="/sales_item/delete/{{ item.id }}" title="{% trans 'Delete' %}"><i class="icon-trash"> </i></a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ item.item_description }}</td>                    
</tr>
```

In my target row, I am loading the html above into the row, when the user clicks on a button.

```
var row = $('tr');
row.load(
        url,        
        function () {                   
            $(".row_edit").click(row_edit);
        }
    );
```

However the problem is that I would have a tr inside a tr:

```
<tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="row_edit" href="/sales_item/edit/{{ item.id }}" title="{% trans 'Edit' %}"><i class="icon-pencil"> </i></a>
            <a href="/sales_item/delete/{{ item.id }}" title="{% trans 'Delete' %}"><i class="icon-trash"> </i></a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ item.item_description }}</td>                    
    </tr>
</tr>
```

How could I say just load me the children of the source when doing a .load() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var row = $('tr');
row.load(
        url + ' td',        
        function () {                   
            $(".row_edit").click(row_edit);
        }
    );
```

---

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');// this is the page fragments selector for jQuery load
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
row.load(
    url,        
    function () {    
        var data = $(this).find("tr").html();               
        $(this).html(data);
        $(".row_edit").click(row_edit);
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I think the other answer is less code and cleaner. Still +1 from me for your help. Thanks